# How about a fun competition to end the quarter?

Tags: discussion

## Due to negative community feedback, this idea is no longer on the table

**Your feedback has been greatly appreciated in this**

---

I have revised the proposition to the following: instead of an emphasis on timeliness, **users will be allocated a certain amount of time (perhaps 1 hour) in which to research and compose the best answer they can.**

Praxis and I have been discussing this idea on chat.   We haven't got as far as a prize (perhaps a bount), but the idea is that several of our leading users can nominate to enter (that means you Richard) and on June 30 at an amenable time for the contestants, a question is posted and the entrants scramble to provide a quality answer first.  Please leave answers to this question to express your opinions.  I cannot stress sufficiently though **that this isn't a mock question or anything** - this will be a legitimate question with a demand for regular quality, just with a twist by adding a time constraint.  The answers would then be judged by a panel.

(Originally we were thinking of launching a competition where whoever answers a question first with a quality answer wins *** BUT no longer the case***. )

Comment: It sounds like the only difference from any other question is that you're scheduling a post time. I'm not sure I really see the point.

Comment: @phantom42 rather than rushing frantically the participants would get a time period to research to give them more time to research the answer thoroughly. Anyway it's just a suggestion and if it's not generally liked that's perfectly fine 

Comment: So we wouldn't post our completed answers for one hour - theoretically all at the same time?

Comment: @phantom42 : To add more background, the discussion started because of how impressed we were with the speed + quality of cde's answer to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92911/help-identifying-what-series-this-doll-comes-from

Comment: @phantom42 correct kind of like a test. The best answer is then judged by a panel

Comment: Well, that's the opposite of what you described in the main post, where you said answerers should scramble to provide a quality answer first. Is it a race, or is it a test?

Comment: I think if this gets a score of -5 I'll forget the idea; make this democratic 

Comment: @phantom42 a test. I'll edit the post to emphasise that more

Comment: So it's basically just about answering questions and the best answers being voted to the top? Sounds like the whole site, only that you pick a special question and make the "panel" to judge the winner a subset of the panel that judges the "winner" for all the other questions.

Answer (score 8):

OMG, a thousand times no.

What you're proposing *is what the site already does*.

Additionally -- and I mean this politely and just food for thought -- you specifically invited @Richard to participate. This means I (and maybe others, who knows ... ) cannot discount the possibility that you, or @Praxis, or others, are biased in his favor.

So, my vote is no. :/

Comment: Thanks for weighing in on this, Slytherincess.  I think the original proposal has been mutated a bit by the feedback...the original idea was to see how *quickly* one can give a high quality answer, and as I said in my comment below the original post above, it was inspired by an event that happened yesterday (where an awesome answer came in at lightning quick speed)....

Comment: About @Richard : I can't hide the fact that I respect him a lot (he gave me some leeway back when I was a fresh user figuring out the site, and he has given me more high quality answers than I thought could be possible)...but I wouldn't say that I am biased towards him, and I doubt N_Soong is either...

Comment: Richard came up in the chat yesterday in the way that he usually does...he has very high rep, he answers a lot of questions and often does so very quickly...it was just all part of the usual banter.  :-)

Comment: Lastly, I believe when @N_Soong first mentioned the idea of a tournament, he said something to the effect of "competition involving the top 10 contributers or so", and so both Richard and you would have been part of it by default.  :-)  All of this being said, you, phantom42, and Chenmunka make solid points and I don't this anyone should proceed with this idea at this point....

Comment: Thanks for your input as well Slytherincess; I've decided to pull this idea off the table.  Thanks for your comments as well @Praxis ;)

Comment: @Praxis - Please don't get me wrong -- I don't think anyone would dismiss **Richard** as unaccomplished. His rise to over 100K rep in a relatively short period of time is truly admirable. And he's fun to chat with. He just *happened* to be the user mentioned in the original post, the one who was specifically invited, and it's that bias is super insidious. It's so insidious, that people who are biased often can't see it in themselves. Or, if they do, they don't admit it to anyone else. That the user in question regarding my comment on bias happened to be **Richard** is truly incidental. :)

Answer (score 3):

No.  I think this would demean the site.

The beauty of SE sites as a whole is that good answers are posted in time after due consideration, not in a hurry to get a prize.

Yes we have the *Enlightened* badge but to win that you have to get a respectable score.
During Winterbash 2013 there was a *Quick on the Draw* hat for fast answers.  Let us leave speed there and not mingle contrived questions with real ones.

Comment: I've updated the proposition; you may wish to re-consider your answer.  Your input is appreciated!

Comment: I note your update, which improves the proposition.  But I still don't like the idea.